# how to unshare a excel worksheet using vbscript not using vba

Tags: excel, vbscript

Could anyone please tell how to unshare an excel worksheet using VBscript and not using VBA?
I tried the following statement and it is not working:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveWorkbook` is a property of the `Application` object. In VBA that object is implicitly used when omitted. In VBScript you have to explicitly use it:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add

If xl.ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then xl.ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
```

You could also use the workbook object that was assigned to the variable `wb`:

```
If wb.MultiUserEditing Then wb.ExclusiveAccess
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, it works for me however i'm getting warning message when i use this command to share and program terminates without executing remaining statements.  could you plse help to solve this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a recent enough version of MS Office to be able to provide further assistance on this. One thing you may want to try, though, is putting `wb.ExclusiveAccess` between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0` and investigate the error you're getting (`Err.Number` and `Err.Description`).

Comment: it works by using objxlap.DisplayAlerts = False if objxlap.activeworkbook.MultiUserEditing Then objxlap.activeworkbook.ExclusiveAccess... It would be great if i get vbscript code to share the unshared active workbook. I tried the below code which does not work ... if objxlap.activeworkbook.ExclusiveAccess then objxlap.activeworkbook.MultiUserEditing

Comment: I don't think there's a separate method for this. You need to enable shared access when saving the workbook (`wb.SaveAs wb.Path, 51, , , , False, 2`).